# Create table from two tables with matching values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one table that looks like this

[image: Output table]

And another table like this

[image: Products table]

I want to create a table combining these two that would group the rows by date, but to match by ID.

I tried with Pivot table but I'm pretty new to Excel, and I couldn't do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to show you that, how two tables can be used to summarize data by using Pivot Table.*

**Step 1:**

[image]

- Create Table and name them (I've used `DataT1` & `DataT2`).
- Select 1st table and create `Pivot Table`.
- Use `Date` in `Rows` to group them.

---

**Step 2:**

- Click `More Tables` from Pivot Table design window.
- Respond the message with `Yes`.
- Now Select `Name` from Table 2 (`DataT2`), for `Rows`.
- Use `Qty` (Quantity) fron table 1 (`DataT1`) and `Price` from second table (`DataT2`) for `Value` with field setting `SUM`.

[image]

**N.B.**

*Another possible method are, an array (CSE) formula as well Power Query.*

Comment: Thanks for replying.

The problem here is, I need the table to show sales per day.

So, showing the sum of values is wrong. I need to calculate QTY multiplied by the PRICE for the given product...

Comment: @Uggrin,,, but what U have written above `that you need data to be grouped on Date` and when U group,, is consolidate /summarizing data, in this situation how could you expect daily sales report?? Please [edit] your post and be clear and loud all about your need and avoid vote to close the question !!

Comment: What good does it do if I have a sum of the prices? Also, if you look at the Pivot Table you posted, all of the sums of qty are the same!? What's that supposed to tell the user?
The point was to group the products under date entered, and calculate price*qty to display how much has been sold of that product for the given date...

Comment: @Uggrin,,, since you are trying to get `Price*Qty` in this case U have to set relation between two tables using common field,,, coz both `Price & Qty` are separated between tables. After setting relation U need to include calculated field (`Pr * QTY`) .